# Expected value given that distribution is positive vs. conditional expectation

Tags: statistics

Referring to [Expected value of normal distribution given that distribution is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88114/expected-value-of-normal-distribution-given-that-distribution-is-positive)

Where is the difference between $E(X$1$_A)$, where $A=[X>0]$, and $E(X∣A)$?

Both seem to express the expected value of $X$ given that $X>0$ which is equal to the conditional expectation

Answer (score 2):

$$E(X\,\mathbf 1_A)=E(X\mid A)\,P(A)$$
$$E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X\gt0})=\int_0^\infty x\,f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
$$P(X\gt0)=\int_0^\infty f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Also here trivially P(A)=P(X>0)

Comment: @Did We refer to $E(X|A)$ as a "conditional expectation".  Does $E(X\,\mathbf{1}_{A})$ also have a name?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Not an established one.

Answer (score 0):

One is 
$$
  \int_0^\infty x f(x) dx
$$
and the other is 
$$
  \frac{\int_0^\infty x f(x) dx}{\int_0^\infty f(x) dx}
$$
where $f$ is the pdf for the Normal distribution.