# Standard Normal Distribution & Altered Expectation

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation

> Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $c$ be a real number. Show
>   that
>   $$\mathbb E((X-c)_+) = g(c)  := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-c^2/2}-cN(-c).$$

I am curious though because I thought if $c = 0$, it implies that expectation should be $$
\Bbb E(X_+) = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}
$$

And that doesn't seem to be the result.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_+]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Perhaps you are confusing it with $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$.

Comment: Yes, but isn't X+ the same as |X|? The link shows I feel it should be different.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88114/expected-value-of-normal-distribution-given-that-distribution-is-positive

Comment: The question in your link is computing a conditional expectation, which explains the extra factor of $2$.

Comment: But isn't this problem a conditional expectation?

Comment: No, it's the expectation of $X_+$. It is related to the conditional expectation by $\mathbb{E}[X_+]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\geq 0]\mathbb{P}(X\geq0)$.