# How do I compute $E(X_1|X_1+X_2>0)$ given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and standard normal?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose $X_1,X_2$ are independent and standard normal. I want to compute $E(X_1|X_1+X_2>0)$. How do I do it?

Here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
E(X_1|X_1+X_2>0)&=\frac{\int_{-x_2}^{+\infty} x_1 f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1}{P(X_1+X_2>0)}\\
&=\frac{\int_{-x_2}^{+\infty} x_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2}dx_1}{0.5}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_2^2}}{0.5}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_2^2}
\end{align}
But I suppose the answer should not have $x_2$ in it. What am I missing?

Comment: What variables should a conditional expectation depend on?

Comment: You can't use the marginal distribution of $X_1$ as you already counted even those $X_2$ making $X_1+X_2\leq 0$.  Use the joint distribution $(X_1,X_2)$ and change variables to $(X_1,X_1+X_2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is that, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, we have that
$$
\mathbf{E}(X_1 | X_1 + X_2 > 0)
= \mathbf{E}(X_2 | X_1 + X_2 > 0).
$$
which we can use to compute
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(X_1 | X_1 + X_2 > 0)
&= \frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{E}(X_1 | X_1 + X_2 > 0) + \mathbf{E}(X_2 | X_1 + X_2 > 0)] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{E}(X_1 + X_2 | X_1 + X_2 > 0) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\mathbf{E}(Z|Z>0),
\end{align*}
where $Z = (X_1 + X_2) / \sqrt{2} \sim N(0, 1)$.

Now, it is a standard fact about Gaussian distributions (details, for example, here: [Expected value of normal distribution given that distribution is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88114/expected-value-of-normal-distribution-given-that-distribution-is-positive)) that $\mathbf{E}(Z | Z>0) = \sqrt{2/\pi}$, from which we have that
$$
\mathbf{E}(X_1 | X_1 + X_2 > 0)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}.
$$