# If Z has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^{2}$, and $Y=Z^{2}$, what would the density function of Y be?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

How would I go about finding this density function?
Thanks

Comment: (1) Do you know how to find the partial distribution function for $Z$? (2) Do you know how to find the partial distribution function for $Y$, if you have $Y = f(Z)$ and you know the PDF of $Z$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925662/proof-that-if-z-is-standard-normal-then-z2-is-distributed-chi-square-1).  $Z^2$ is distributed as Chi-Square. So possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925662/proof-that-if-z-is-standard-normal-then-z2-is-distributed-chi-square-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function for $Y$ is:
$$
F_Y(y)=\operatorname{Prob}(Y<y)=\operatorname{Prob}(-\sqrt{y}<z<\sqrt{y})=F_Z(\sqrt{y})-F_Z(-\sqrt{y})=2F_Z(\sqrt{y})-1
$$
Now to get the density differentiate with respect to $y$, and of course to differentiate $2F_Z(\sqrt{y})$ you use the chain rule and the fact that the derivative of $F_Z(x)$ with respect to $x$ is $f_Z(x)$ the density of $Z$, which you know as $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: In fact, what you end up with is a [chi-squared](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) distribution

Comment: You may know that and i may know that (with 1 DF) but it does not answer the question as asked which was how you go about finding the density function.

Comment: @ConradTurner Thanks for the answer! I understand the answer but just had one more query. I've got the formula for the normal probability density function but to differentiate the cumulative distribution function for Y stated above, I would need to find cumulative distribution function for Z up to $\sqrt{y}$, but how could I do that?

Comment: @ConradTurner I thought it was useful to have some kind of relevant link

Comment: @SamuelOpiyo To differentiate $2F_Z(\sqrt{y})$ you use the chain rule and the fact that the derivative of $F_Z(x)$ with respect to $x$ is $f_Z(x)$ the density of $Z$.

Comment: @ConradTurner I get that Conrad, great answer!