# How can I find the distribution of a stochastic variable X^2 if X is normal standard distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am considering a stochastic variable X that is standard normal distributed i.e.
$$
F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt
$$
How do I find out the distribution of $X^2$?

/Gus

Comment: The sum of squares of $k$ independent standard normal RVs is chi square with $k$ degrees of freedom, I believe. So in this case, $k=1$. I also think chi square is a special case of gamma.

Comment: Well, there's no way of knowing that if you aren't familiar with chi squares.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71537/321264

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $Y=X^2$. We presumably want to find the density function of $Y$. First we (sort of) find the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$. Note that $Y$ is never negative. For $y\gt 0$, we have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X^2\le y)=\Pr(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y}).\tag{1}$$
It follows that
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.\tag{2}$$
We *could* integrate. However, if all we want is to find the density function $f_Y(y)$, we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate the integral in (2). Using the Chain Rule, we get
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{y}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y/2}$$
(for $y\gt 0$).

Comment: I can not up vote because my reputation sucks or similar, but this answers my question, thank you.

Comment: @Gus I upvoted for you :)