# $X\sim N(0,1)$, find the generating function of $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

If $X\sim N(0,1)$, I need find the generating function of $Y=X^2$. The exercise says me that I should not solve the integral (which is I presume $\int e^{tx^2}f(x)dx$). It also says:

$$E(e^{tY}) = E(e^{tX^2})$$

and that any probability distribution function $f(x)$ has $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ dx = 1$

How should I solve it? I know I must find $M_{X^2}(t) = E(e^{tX^2})$. I can't, however, solve the integral. Which methods are left? I don't know any.

Comment: This is known as the Chi-Square distribution with 1 degree of freedom, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71537/derivation-of-chi-squared-pdf-with-one-degree-of-freedom-from-normal-distributio?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y=X^2$

$$E(e^{tY})=E(e^{tX^2})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\dfrac{x^2(1-2t)}{2}}dx$$

I think you can do next steps.

Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\sigma$$

So you have to find $\sigma$ here, that's all.

Btw $Y$ follows **Chi-Square distribution** with 1 degree of freedom

Comment: Should I recognize this as another type of distribution?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You just have to complete the integration... note that this integration is related to $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$ which is $1$. So you just have to find $\sigma$ here.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs $Y$ is definitely another distribution. Hint: Google Chi-Square distribution