# What is the probability density function of $Y=Z_1^2+...+Z_k^2$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

1. Let $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. What is the probability density function of $X=Z^2$?
2. Let $Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be $k$  independent standard normal random variables. What is the probability density function of $Y=Z_1^2+...+Z_k^2$? (Hint: compute $\Gamma(1/2)$ by an adequate change of variables, then use the distribution of $Z^2$ from part one).

**My Attempt**

We know the p.d.f. for $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is $$\phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$$
So the c.d.f. for $X=Z^2$ is
\begin{align}
F_X(x)&=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(Z^2\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(z\leq\sqrt{x})=F_Z(\sqrt{x})\\
&=\int_0^\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(1-e^{-x/2})
\end{align}
Our p.d.f. is the derivative of this, so:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x/2}$$

The part that I am stuck on is the second part. How should I handle $Y$ without knowing the value of $k$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution)

Comment: That pdf is clearly wrong. How did you compute the integral? You can immediately tell the pdf is wrong, because it does not integrate to $1$; actually its integral is $\infty$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71537/321264

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

$$X=Z^2\sim \chi_{(1)}^2$$

$$Y=\sum_k Z_k^2\sim \chi_{(k)}^2$$

Let's see why:

First your error:

$$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z^2\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{x}\leq Z\leq \sqrt{x})=\Phi_Z(\sqrt{x})-\Phi_Z(-\sqrt{x})$$

Derivating you get your density

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\phi(\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\phi(-\sqrt{x})=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\phi(\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x/2}$$

Now consider that

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Thus substitute in the result and verify that $f_X(x)$ is the density of a $\text{Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$ which is a chi-square with 1 d.o.f.

---

As the second part is concerned, using the result found in 1. you can immediately get the solution using the additivity property of Gamma distribution which can be easy proved using MGF or Characteristic function

Comment: Kindly can I know why 2 donwvotes to my answer?

Comment: A typo in your first computation : it should be $F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z^2\leqslant{\color{red}x})$. Also, you didn't give the value of $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ !

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq : I  am typing by the cell phone...it is not possible to have a preview